# Wordpress: Problem adding comment functionality to a page

Tags: wordpress, comments

if anyone can figure this out, thanks a million!

I wanted to have my wp install at root level where the homepage displays excerpts of latest blogs but I still wanted the top navigation to point to a "blog" page www.mydomain.com/blog which displays the full latest blog (and allows comments).

I thought I was being clever by creating a new Page Template just for this blog page - I copy/pasted the single post code into this template and created a static page called blog using that template. My permalink structure ensures if would be found like so www.mydomain.com/blog.

It all works beautifully except no comments functionality - I tried googling and trying a few things but comments_template('', true) and variations at various points in the page didnt do the trick. Best I can do is: comments_popup_link('No Comments | Click to Comment', '1 Comment | Click to Comment', '% Comments | Click to Comment');

Please smart people, come to my rescue :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a page and make it your front page.

Visit the Administration > Settings > Reading panel and under Front page displays, you can choose to set any (published) Page or Posts Page as the Front Page.

Create a page called 'blog', and choose this as your posts page in the [reading panel.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_SubPanel)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a lot better solution than the one used by the OP. This way you won't have a problem with the comments, and you can always change where your blog is located or what your front page is if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I tried your suggestion and again, it didn't display comments. It seems like even though its a "page" it's not admitting to being one. I went into comment-template.php and commented out the lines:

Comment: woops....if ( !(is_single() || is_page() || $withcomments) || empty($post) )
  return;

Comment: sorry about multi posting - it works when that line is removed - why might the page not be returning true to is_page() and how can I find out what it is? Thanks!

Comment: OK - solved this with a simple wp_reset_query(); Thanks for all your help and I will structure the blog as you suggest....cheers!